# Instagram search user api always return empty result with success code

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are invoking instagram search users api to get profile list as

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q={search-term}&access_token={access-token}](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=%7Bsearch-term%7D&access_token=%7Baccess-token%7D)

but we are getting always empty result with success code as

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

Our search term would be always instagram username i.e. username portion from https://www.instagram.com/username/

I remember this was working before 2-3 months. Any other are facing similar issue?

Comment: are u in sandbox mode?

Comment: yes. I guess we figured it out that it is due to sandbox mode. Earlier before 2-3 months while creating POC we have used access token from some other production app.

Comment: btw thanks for your comment, please post if you know any other scenario.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you already figured out your problem. In case anyone else is having the same problem, here's a [short article summarizing how Instagram's Sandbox Mode works](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s).

TL;DR

> “Sandbox mode” is the (unintuitively-named) gatekeeper walling off
>   most of what you want to do. This is the default status for all
>   clients, that have not undergone the strict submission process. An API
>   client in sandbox mode has extremely limited permissions. In fact, it
>   has fewer permissions than an anonymous user viewing public content
>   because your app basically lives on a tiny desert island in which you
>   are the only Instagram user and only your past twenty posts exist. So,
>   for example, the /media/search endpoint will only return the media you
>   uploaded near a given location, excluding the media from everyone else
>   or any posts beyond your last twenty.

So your API call is succeeding. It just isn't finding any results because it can only "see" other sanbox users for your client.